# Opening GUI version of Maple from command line

Tags: user-interface, command-line, maple

I'm sure this is stupidly simple but I just am not seeing how to do it.  I have modules available for Maple 16,17, or 18 I don't have a preference on which one I use I just need to be able to open the GUI version.  I can load the module and open Maple no problem in the command line but that isn't what I need, I really need the gui version, how do I do this from the command line?? ....any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows: run `maplew.exe` from the Maple install directory (usually C:/Program Files/Maple##/bin ).

In OSX: run `./xmaple` from the Maple install directory ( /Library/Frameworks/Maple.framework/Versions/##/bin/ )

In Linux: run `./xmaple` from the Maple install directory

Now depending on how your modules are stored, you have a few options to load those on initialization.

To open an existing worksheet (Maple .mw file) in the GUI version of Maple, you can also add the file path to the command line call. For example, `./xmaple <file>`

If you would like to run a command on startup you can also add the -c (command) flag to the call, for example, `./xmaple -c "with(Statistics):"` will load the Statistics package. You might also use the [`read`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=read&term=read) command here to read in a file.

If you existing scripts that you'd like to run on startup (including Maple language files mpl), you can use the -i flag to read from an initialization file: `./xmaple -i "PathToScriptFile"` This will load the script file without any output.

For more on the available flags, type in `./maple --help`

You can read more details on command line options here: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=maple

Comment: I have my environment set to load the module cshrc file, what I was missing was xmaple.... maple just simply launches in the command line, where xmaple opens the gui.  Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I want to mention some other things.

In Windows:

add `D:\Program Files\Maple 18\bin.X86_64_WINDOWS\;` to the *PATH* in System Environment Variables.
Then type `maplew`, Maple GUI can be open, while  type `cmaple` Command-line Maple will be open.